# Is the PDF of the compound distribution of an exponential distribution with a beta-distributed parameter analytic?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, probability-distributions

Say we have a random variable which acts like an exponential random variable but its rate parameter is drawn from a Beta distribution. Now, [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_probability_distribution) (yeah, maybe I should find a book on this stuff....), the pdf of this compound distribution can be found as follows

$p_H(x|\alpha) = {\displaystyle \int\limits_\theta p_F(x|\theta)\,p_G(\theta|\alpha) \operatorname{d}\!\theta}$

(where $p_F$ is the pdf of an exponential distribution, $p_G$ is the same for a Beta distribution, $\alpha$ is the parameters of the Beta distribution (in reality this will be $\alpha, \beta$) and $\theta$ is the variable parameterising the exponential distribution and ranges over the positive reals).

I want to check whether this is analytic, because if it is then I can use [certain fast numerical integration methods](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31550/Fast-Numerical-Integration) to approximate probabilities with it.

Turning again to [Prof. 'Pedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function#Properties_of_analytic_functions), I learn that

> The sums, products, and compositions of analytic functions are analytic.
>   The reciprocal of an analytic function that is nowhere zero is analytic.

Now, given that the exponential and Gamma functions are analytic and nowhere zero, with the above I infer that the exponential and Beta pdfs are both analytic, and so should be their product, the integrand above.

I am inferring from [some lecture notes I found online](http://www.phys.ufl.edu/~pjh/teaching/phz3113/notes/week12.pdf) (<- link to .pdf file) that the integral is therefore also analytic:

[image: image showing statement from lecture notes]

From this I am tentatively concluding that the above pdf is actually analytic. Could anyone please let me know if this conclusion is right, and help me formalise an argument for it?

Comment: analytic in $x$ ? if $p_F(z |\theta)$ is analytic in $z$ and your integral $F(z)$ converges uniformly for $|z-z_0| < r$ then $F(z)$ is analytic on $|z-z_0| < r$ ([Morera's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem) : that the integral for $F(z)$ converges uniformly on some region means we have $\int_C F(z) dz = 0$ for $C$ any closed contour in this region and hence $F(z)$ is analytic there)

Comment: Yes, analytic in $x$ on the real interval $(0, \infty)$

Comment: no, complex analytic in $x$ on $Re(x) >0, |Im(x) | < T$

Comment: I mean that for the purposes of my question the function is defined in the real interval I stated. I am dealing with probability distributions defined only on the positive reals.

Comment: No, that's what I meant, for using the complex analysis theorem, you need to deal with the (natural) analytic continuation of your probability distributions. You'll agree that the exponential distribution has a very natural continuation to $x$ complex (and the beta distribution too)

Comment: So as I said, all you have to do is to find some region $U$ in the complex plane such that your integral converges uniformly/absolutely when $x \in U$